# How to get values from EditText created in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

i mean editText created programmatically. I want to get the data inputted from those editText i created.

These are i've done so far.

**VARIABLES**

```
private GridLayout gridLayout;

//for tasks
int rowIndex = 2;
int colIndex = 1;
int rowIndex2 = 2;
int colIndex2 = 0;

int i=0;
int j=0;

//database variables
MyDBAdapter dbhandler;
```

To be able to create an editText in a gridlayout by a button click.

When "add new Task" button is clicked:

```
public void addTask(View view) {
        i++;
        Map<String, Integer> idsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String tname = "task" + Integer.toString(i);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
        param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
        editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
        editText.setText(tname);
        editText.setLayoutParams(param);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex2);
        param2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex2);
        textView.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        textView.setLayoutParams(param2);

        if (rowIndex > 1) {
            textView.setText("TASK "+Integer.toString(i)+": ");
            editText.setId(i);
            idsMap.put(tname, i);
        }

        gridLayout.addView(editText);
        gridLayout.addView(textView);
        rowIndex++;
        rowIndex2++;
        this.j = 0;
    }
```

When "Add new Subtask" button is clicked:

```
public void addSubtask(View view) {
        j++;
        Map<String, Integer> idsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String taskno = "task" + Integer.toString(i) + "subtask" + Integer.toString(j);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
        param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
        editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
        editText.setText(taskno);
        editText.setLayoutParams(param);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex2);
        param2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex2);
        textView.setPadding(30,0,0,0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        textView.setLayoutParams(param2);

        if (rowIndex > 1) {
            textView.setText("Subtask "+Integer.toString(j)+": ");
            editText.setId(j);
            idsMap.put(taskno, j);
        }

        gridLayout.addView(editText);
        gridLayout.addView(textView);
        rowIndex++;
        rowIndex2++;
    }
```

**IT WOULD LOOK LIKE THIS FOR EXAMPLE:**

**TASK 1:** ___________

Subtask 1: ________

Subtask 2: ________

**TASK 2:** ___________

Subtask 1: ________

**TASK 3:** ___________

Assuming the user is done inputting the necessary info and clicks the submit button. **THE PROBLEM COMES IN. I DONT KNOW HOW TO GET ALL THE VALUES BASED on the number of editText created by the user.**

```
public void submit(){

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //implementation
                String task1 = task1.getText().toString(); // It would only get task1
    String subtask1 = task1subtask1.getText().toString(); // It would only get subtask1 of task 1

            }    
    }
```

That kind of implementation is not usable since i dont know how many editTexts of tasks and subtasks that the user created. HELPPPP T___T

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create an Edit Text use [View.generateId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) to generate an ID, store that ID in an HashMap or loop your container Views with getChildAt() and then, if its an EditText get its value.

Comment: it wont recognize View.generateId(); it doesn't have a class like that

Comment: that method is available from API 17 only, but it doesn't really matter, you can even avoid setting an ID

Comment: i need to set an id to get their values\

Comment: no you don't, just loop container children and then check which one is an edittext

Comment: i need their ids cause i have to get their values and put it in a database

Comment: you do not need IDs, but at this point i don't think you are understanding

Comment: i need it. to get their values. like this -> String edittextname = edittext_id.getText().toString(); and this edittextname string will be inserted to a database. but how could i get the value if i don't know the id?

Comment: Just do if (viewGroup.grtChildAt(i) instance of EditText) edittextname = ((EditText) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).getText()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set a custom tag for each edittext that you create.

You can determinate a specific generic tag for "Task" and an other for "Subtask" and after each creation, you set the tag to your edittext like that :

edittext.setTag(KEY, "task_X") where X is a incremental id.

After that, you can enumerate all children of your main container and check tags'children

Comment: i did. already done. the problem is that I DONT KNOW HOW TO GET ALL THE VALUES BASED on the number of editText created by the user.

Comment: i have already assigned them all unique ids each. but i dont know how many were created by the user. and how i could get the values

Comment: When user create a edittext, you know that because your creation's function is called so you can count the number of tasks and subtasks are created. But i don't know if is the right solution... The FrankMonza's solution seems to be a good option

Comment: there is no View.generateId() class. it wont recognize that class

Comment: There isn't no : myNewEdittext.generateViewId () ? This method is herited by EditText because EditText herite of View class. What API are you using ?

Comment: yes there is none. i dont know why. I read some sources it depends on the API.

Comment: You can mix my proposition and the FrankMonza's proposition : use tag like id and store then in a hashmap

Answer (score 0):

```
List<EditText> allEdittext = new ArrayList<EditText>();

public void addSubtask(View view) {
            j++;
            Map<String, Integer> idsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            String taskno = "task" + Integer.toString(i) + "subtask" + Integer.toString(j);
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
            param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
            editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
            editText.setText(taskno);
            editText.setLayoutParams(param);

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex2);
            param2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex2);
            textView.setPadding(30,0,0,0);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            textView.setLayoutParams(param2);

            if (rowIndex > 1) {
                textView.setText("Subtask "+Integer.toString(j)+": ");
                editText.setId(j);
                idsMap.put(taskno, j);
            }

    allEdittext.add(editText);


            gridLayout.addView(editText);
            gridLayout.addView(textView);
            rowIndex++;
            rowIndex2++;
        }
```

Then your get the values from the edit text

```
public void submit(){

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //implementation
                String task1 = task1.getText().toString(); // It would only get task1
//i will be the position
    String subtask1 = allEdittext.get(i).getText().toString();// It would only get subtask1 of task 1

            }    
    }
```

Like this you can modify the code for addtask() function

Comment: String subtask1 = allEdittext.get(i).getText().toString(); <== this will not be in loop?

Comment: yeah it should be in loop and the loop size will be the no of edit text available.

Comment: wont worked. i had to connect the task with the subtasks. it should two dimensional array. not just one.